# MYSQL query balance

Tags: mysql

I have two table in my database.

[image]

I want to create query to display balance like:

[image]

I want to:

1. sum "order qty"
2. group "inventory" item
3. display "inventory" item with 0 on "order qty"

Comment: can you post post what you have on http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested and working:

```
SELECT inventory.inv_id, inventory.item, inventory.qty, 
COALESCE(SUM( `order`.qty ) , 0 ) AS sum_qty, 
COALESCE((inventory.qty - SUM( `order`.qty)) , 0) AS balance
FROM inventory
LEFT JOIN `order` ON inventory.inv_id = `order`.inv_id
GROUP BY `inventory`.inv_id
ORDER BY inventory.inv_id ASC
```

Comment: How I can achieve to display:

Comment: How I can achieve to display: inventory item qty on balance column when order qty is "0" ?  like inventory qty=10 - order qty=0 = balance=10